# Cannot run update due to a dpkg error with burg-theme-minimal-sir

Tags: burg

I cannot run an update or indeed run $: apt-get remove  due to a dpkg error with a package that's a part of super-boot-manager. Running an update returns:

```
dpkg: error processing burg-theme-minimal-sir (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I tried removing this package alone, with the same error, also trying to remove super-boot-manager returns:

```
(Reading database ... 225474 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing burg-theme-minimal-sir ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing burg-theme-minimal-sir (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Removing super-boot-manager ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
burg-theme-minimal-sir
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm sort of stuck now and Google has failed me. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Or does anyone know a way for fixing this?

Comment: actually I fixed it by running
    sudo mkdir /boot/burg/locale && sudo apt-get remove burg-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the error logs I realized I just need to create a locale directory in /boot/burg/. After that it was all fine.
If someone encounters this error (which I assume occurred in the first place due to my sloppy installation of burg-manager) just run:
    sudo mkdir /boot/burg/locale && sudo apt-get remove burg-manager

Answer (score 0):

What the output is telling you is that the package's post-installation script is failing (failure is not acceptable to dpkg, so it just considers the package broken). If we look inside the contents of the package, we see that the script simply runs `sudo update-burg`. From your extended output listing, it seems that there is an error due to missing a required file (`/boot/burg/locale`), which is likely the cause of the update-burg process' failure.

In short, unless you have done something very specific to have provoked this failure, it seems you have discovered a bug, and should probably report it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have a broken package:
You can check out for broken packages in Synaptic Package Manager.

You have:
Errors were encountered while processing:
burg-theme-minimal-sir
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Run in terminal

## sudo apt-get autoremove burg-theme-minimal-sir

## sudo apt-get update

Then if you want to remove Super Boot Manager you can do it from the program.

However, if you want to reinstall SPM, type in terminal:

## sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager

## sudo apt-get update

## sudo apt-get install buc super-boot-manager

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
this is worked for me on ubuntu 12.04

http://code.google.com/p/burg/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=17

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.